# Powershell Try/Catch based on specific text?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

My script is throwing an error like so:

```
ConvertFrom-StringData : Data item 'a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e' in line 'a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e  =  My
Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-10-08 21-46-21 (2).mov' is already defined.
At P:\scripts\code\pcloud_sync.ps1:66 char:179
+ ... ace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ConvertFrom-StringData], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromStringDataCommand
```

I want to catch this error by the "is already defined" text and then run a separate command if this is caught before the script reruns the code - possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$_.Exception.Message` attribute to get the exception message as string and then use `-match` statement to check if it's follows particular pattern.

```
$Here = @'
Msg1 = The string parameter is required.
Msg2 = Credentials are required for this command.
Msg1 = The specified variable does not exist.
'@

try {
    ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $Here
} catch {
    if($_.Exception.Message -match "is already defined") {
        Write-Output "Do Something"
    }
}
```